# Escape SQL Server connection string with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, sql-server

I need to compose a SQL Server connection string on-the-fly in my C# code and I was curious if there's a built-in way of doing it? So far I have this:

```
string connectionString = "Server=" + server + 
      "; Database=" + db + 
      "; User Id=" + userName + 
      "; password=" + pass + 
      "; Connection Timeout=15";
```

And also, do I need to include all names in double quotes as such?

```
string connectionString = "Server=\"" + server + 
      "\"; Database=\"" + db + 
      "\"; User Id=\"" + userName + 
      "\"; password=\"" + pass + 
      "\"; Connection Timeout=15";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class, which does all of this for you and gives you convenient properties.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I found this link that shows how to use it: http://www.ginktage.com/2011/05/creating-connectionstring-with-sqlconnectionstringbuilder-class-in-c/